# How can I route based on the prefix of a slug in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a requirement for SEO purposes where I need to route by State but have the URL all look like a sentence. For example if I'm selling cars I would need:

http://domain.com/new-york-cars-for-sale

How can I route this? I tried:

match '(:state)-cars-for-sale' => 'cars#index', :as => :cars

No go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
match '*state-cars-for-sale' => 'cars#index', :as => :cars
```

Then the state will be passed in to params[:state].

[See rails routing docs on route-globbing for more details on how to use the `*` operator in the routes file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using globbing.